How can I profile my dynamic memory allocator?
I'm developing my own allocator and using the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to interpose libcs malloc function.
I want to profile my code when running some applications, such as measuring the time each function takes relative to the total execution time.
How can I accurately measure the time taken by each function in my code when an application runs?
I know I can use gettimeofday() from sys/time.h to measure time, but it introduces its own overhead.
I've considered using tools like perf or gprof, but I'm not sure how to use them in an environment where I need to interpose using LD_PRELOAD.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


I'm not sure how to use them in an environment where I need to interpose using LD_PRELOAD

Using perf should just work™:
perf record env LD_PRELOAD=./mymalloc.so /path/to/program

Using gprof will not work out of the box, because nothing would call the "save coverage" hook (_mcleanup), unless you also build the main program with -pg.
If you build both the main a.out and the malloc interposer with -pg, gprof should also just work™.
